# Google Charts - Columns extremely thin

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I am currently trying to use Google charts and more specificly [this Angular implementation](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts).

I am trying to make a simple column graph but the lines are ending up extremely thin:
[image: Graph]

I am currently setting the style and data as follows in my HTML:

```
<google-chart [type]="revenueChartType" [data]="revenueChartData" [columnNames]="revenueChartNames" [title]="revenueChartTitle" [options]="revenueChartOptions"></google-chart>
```

With my bindings as follows:

```
revenueChartData = [];
revenueChartType: string = "ColumnChart";
revenueChartNames: Array<string> = ["Months", "Revenue"];
revenueChartTitle: string = `Revenue for ${new Date().getFullYear()}`
revenueChartOptions: any = {}
```

And then I am populating the data as follows:

```
//Loop through each item in revenuePerMonth
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if (json.revenuePerMonth[i] != undefined) {
        //Push items into the array
        this.revenueChartData.push([json.revenuePerMonth[i].month, json.revenuePerMonth[i].total]);
    } else {
        this.revenueChartData.push([i, 10000]);
    }
}
```

Is there an option or something I need to set to increase the width of the bars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following option, which is supposed to adjust the width of the bars...

```
bar: {
  groupWidth: '80%'
}
```

however, using a discrete axis (string data) will resolve the issue.
when loading the data, convert the numbers to strings...

```
json.revenuePerMonth[i].month.toString()
```

-- and --

```
i.toString()
```

Comment: You're a lifesaver! That fixed the issue @WhiteHat, thank you so much. If you update your answer I will mark it accepted :D